# Use function as an argument in Pythone

Tags: python

I cannot figure why my following code is giving error:

```
def get_two():
    return 'two'

def get_three():
    return 'three'

def return_real(text, function):
    my_string = text + function()
    return my_string

print(return_real('one', get_two()))
```

I got the following error:

```
error: File "...", line 14, in <module>
print(return_real('one', get_two()))
File "...", line 10, in return_real
my_string = text + function()
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

I was expecting following output:
'onetwo'

Comment: You need to pass the function: `get_two` *not* the result of calling the function: `get_two()`. -- `return_real('one', get_two)`

Answer (score 1):

When you pass the function with parentheses it does not pass the name of the function but the returning value from the function.

There are two ways to do this.

#### 1. remove the parentheses when passing the function name as a parameter

```
def return_real(text, function):
    my_string = text + function()
    return my_string

print(return_real('one', get_two))
```

#### 2. Or, Remove the parentheses from the `function` variable inside the `return_real` function.

```
def return_real(text, function):
    my_string = text + function
    return my_string

print(return_real('one', get_two()))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
my_string = text + function()
```

Here you are thinking the function is called here but that's not the case, value returned by the function is used here so the code should be like this:

```
my_string = text + function
```